# Free space from files filled with 0 (null)

Tags: windows-7, ntfs

On Windows 7 with NTFS filesystem - I have a bunch of files which contents are purely nulls (confirmed with text editor [pspad](http://www.pspad.com)). Is it possible that I can reclaim this space transparently? That is, if these files are subsequently opened for writing, the space is then allocated.

Understandably this could create a situation of overprovisioning and thus writes could fail if there is not enough free space - this is acceptable in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest thing would be to use NTFS compression on these files.

Windows also supports [Sparse Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365564%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You would need to be able to modify the programs that create the files to use this.

Comment: NTFS compression is a good idea, it will require some jiggerypokery on my side as the directory contains a mix of seldom/heavily accessed files - but it would work. It's a shame I can't force Spare Files from my end rather than needing application support - oh well.